# Record Date values based on another cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am a beginner in VBA.

I have a Column "A" can have multiple values, of which 2 are "Impact Assessed" or "Ready for retesting".

Problem Statement - I want to record the dates when cell's value is changed to Impact Assessed and Ready for Retesting in 2 separate columns - Column B and Column C, respectively.

Below is my code -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng As Range
  If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("AA:AA"), Target)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Select Case (rng.Value)
        Case "2 - Impact Assessed": rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Case "4 - Ready for retesting": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
    End Select
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    'If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A:A"), Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c in rng.cells
            Select Case LCase(c.Value)
                Case "impact assessed": c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
                Case "ready": c.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
            End Select
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

FYI = `Range(Target.Address)` is the same (in this case) as `Target` - no need to get the address just to turn that back into a range.

Comment: Tysm. This works but 1 issue - Copy paste on multiple cells disables the macros. So, I removed the "Target.Count Large" row. Gives me an error.

Comment: Tysm. This works but 2 issues - 
1. Does this script have a limitation on Formula driven cells. My column A (that contains values - Impact assessed and read) is formula driven. IF I manually update the values the script works, not otherwise.
2. Copy paste on multiple cells disables the macros. So, I removed the "Target.Count Large" row. Gives me an error.

Comment: You can't use worksheet_change for reacting to changes in formula output - those do not trigger the event.  You need to use worksheet_calculate instead.

Comment: Hi Tim I did, but it now gives me a compile error. I changed to Worksheet and Calculate from the dropdown options as well. Not sure.

Comment: If you have updated your code and it's giving you errors, you can either post a new question with your new code and a description of the problem, or edit your question above and add the new code (do not replace the previous code as you have answers here addressing it)

Comment: got it. I can revert and add a new question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have made the code as versatile as possible. Just change the constants and, if need be, the search criteria in the `Criteria` variable to suit your worksheet and you can change your sheet as you like without needing to modify the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 040

    Const TriggerClm    As String = "A"         ' change to suit
    Const WriteToClm    As String = "B"         ' the second one is next to this

    Dim Rng             As Range                ' working range
    Dim C               As Long                 ' WriteToClm
    Dim Criteria()      As String               ' selected values from TriggerClm
    Dim i               As Integer              ' index to Criteria()

    ' don't respond to changes of multiple cells such as Paste or Delete
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' respond to changes in cells from row 2 to
    ' one cell below the last used row in the trigger column
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, TriggerClm), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, TriggerClm).End(xlUp).Offset(1))

    If Not Application.Intersect(Rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' intentionally all lower case because comparison
        ' is carried out case insensitive
        ' First item's date is in WriteToClm
        Criteria = Split("impact assessed,ready for retesting", ",")

        For i = UBound(Criteria) To 0 Step -1
            If StrComp(Target.Value, Criteria(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
        Next i

        ' i = -1 if no match was found
        If i >= 0 Then
            C = Columns(WriteToClm).Column + i
            Cells(Target.Row, C).Value = Date
        End If
 End If
End Sub
```